# OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory

Tags: java, out-of-memory, netty

I'm using `PooledByteBufAllocator` as the default allocator for my server and `ByteToMessageDecoder`. I'm storing the ByteBufs/messages created by the decoder (i.e. calling retain on them) and processing them at a later time. These `ByteBufs` are of size 4000 bytes.

When I blast the server with the 4k byte messages, the first ~75000 messages all succeed, then I see

> "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory" exceptions even
>   though the sum of all messages is only 300mb. Also, note that I use
>   the following to set the JVM's direct memory limit:
>   -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2g

Where is the rest of the memory ~1700mb going?

I'm not calling allocate from my source at all and It seems unlikely to be overhead.

I've noticed that the ByteBufs that the decoder allocates have a capacity that is equal to roughly two times the message size (i.e. 8014), but that only accounts to another ~300mb (if all the capacity is allocated), which still doesn't explain where the rest of the direct memory is being consumed.

Strangely, when I copy the ByteBufs allocated from the decoder and release the original buffers and process the copies later, then I am able to do ~500000 requests/messages (amounts to 2gb of direct memory), which is what I expect.

I noticed that the copied ByteBufs have a capacity which is equal to the message size, which is less than the decoder's ByteBufs capacity.

Note: I am using netty 4.0.35.Final